# Document a method returning a lambda

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard, yardoc

I have an object with a method returning a lambda:

```rb
class Book
  def mark_page(marker_color)
    lambda do |page|
      page.mark(marker_color)
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to document this `Book#mark_page` method using [yardoc](https://yardoc.org) syntax. However, I cannot find anything about lambdas in this documentation.

Intuitively, I'd go for something like:

```rb
# @return [Proc(Page)]
```

Since [yardoc.org/types](https://yardoc.org/types) is parsing it as:

> a Proc containing (a Page)

<sub>PS: not so sure about the <kbd>documentation</kbd> tag. Feel free to remove it if not appropriate...</sub>

Comment: `# @return [Proc]` See https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return. Note that you're returning a `Proc` object, so the P needs to be uppercase, not lowercase. Not sure what you think `{Page}` means in this context, but it doesn't belong.

Comment: @anothermh — the `{Page}` is the whole point of my question. I want to tell that I am returning a `Proc` which takes a `Page` as argument. Quite similar to JSDoc when you return a function and explicit it's arguments. From your given link, I end up thinking `Proc(Page)` is the closest solution (https://yardoc.org/types). But I'm not sure it is semantically correct.

Comment: @anothermh hence my question for a clearer way of doing so...